# QT Creator dynamic class name reference

Tags: c++, qt, class, qt-creator

I am developing an instant message application in QT Creator, and I have a class called "im" that opens as a QWidget window. I want to dynamically name a new class instance so that I can later refer to the existing window instead of creating a new one. Specifically, I would like to give the class a name stored in a QString variable, which in this case represents the peer's name.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've tried the following approaches without success:

Using a QString variable to name the instance:

```
QString variable_name = peer_name;
im variable_name = new im();
```

Directly using the peer name as the instance name:

```
im peer_name = new im();
```

However, these examples wouldn't work as intended. I am aware that shell scripting might handle this differently, but I'm specifically looking for a solution in QT Creator using C++.

How can I dynamically name a new class instance in QT Creator, such that I can later refer to the existing window using the peer's name stored in a QString variable?

Comment: In C++, you cannot directly create variable names dynamically at runtime as you were trying to do with the QString. Variable names are determined at compile-time, and you cannot change them during program execution. However, you can achieve your desired functionality using a different approach by using a QMap or a QHash data structure.

Comment: I see.. I had found something on QMap... but will have to further look into it I would guess... thank you for the short notice...

Comment: Do you even need a variable for this? If the QWidget you are creating has a parent you can use [find_child()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild) on the parent to get a pointer to the widget at any time.

Comment: That is the other methode I had been trying... soo.. I have to assign parent... will see how it works out.. ty

Comment: But, perhaps, what we are actually looking for is some healthy information exchange between public/private slots and variables... 
Must be the use of public slots and variables as well...
Even so, hash is not completely ruled out though.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into something like this as the answer:

```
QHash<QString, im *> hash;

im *im_one = new im();
im_one->setWindowTitle("one");

im_one->show();

hash["one"] = im_one;
qInfo() << hash["one"];   // gives memory address

im *x = hash.value("one");
//x->setWindowTitle("two");
x->show();
```

in the end only one window appears to be visible... thus I am inclined to believe that it may be inherited ... but still have to double check.
Seems to be pretty close... have to see myself in between the rest of the code.

*** EDIT *** indeed managed to get 'some' working form... so this should be the answer.

*** EDIT *** sometimes the code is breaking, but once again, it did hold up together...

*** EDIT *** on windows it does kind of crash... but not this particular example... hmm... maybe there is some other problem... hmm got it working after all.

Comment: pass the hash game...